# Scala: passing impure function to a HoF

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pure-function

I came across a piece of scala code which makes use of map function in a very unexpected manner:

```
myList.map(item => someImpureFunction(item))
```

someImpureFunction has return type Unit.

Is it an acceptable way of doing FP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `someImpureFunction` returns `Unit` it implies that the function performs  some side effect e.g. writes to a database or standard output, so in that case, it's better to use:

```scala
myList.foreach(item => someImpureFunction(item))
```

If you want to write pure FP code you should take a look at deferring the execution of side effects (a good example is [Cats IO](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/2.x/datatypes/io))

Comment: Or just `myList.foreach(someImpureFunction)`